# python.exe file is not found by cmd even though folder path added to PATH env var

Tags: python, windows, cmd, virtualenv

I downloaded python, but afterwards I included the path of the folder into `PATH` environment variable, but afterwards can not run `python` from the `cmd` prompt — it is not recognized. In similar case I made **virtual env** through python. First time it ran perfect, but after restart my computer it working but the commands is not recognized.

I don't understand the problem. First time it works perfectly but after restart it does not. I again create another virtual env using anaconda prompt. It working perfectly, but I can not do again and again... What is the solution?

Comment: A virtualenv needs to be `activate`d before it works in any given shell. By contrast, if your goal is just to make Python available in newly-opened shells, you don't need a virtualenv for that at all -- you just need to make sure your system `PATH` includes the directory with the Python executable.

Comment: What is the output from the `ECHO %PATH%` command? Please edit the question and past the text into it. No screenshots.